# ArcGIS query layer shape=long integer and not geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query-layer

I want to add a Query Layer in ArcMap to eventually publish WMS services. WMS services cannot be created with a selection layer so I though I would try the Query Layer variation. My problem is that I always get a table without geometry as my result. The SHAPE field does not have "geometry field" but instead a "long integer" field. I am using MSSQL2012 with ArcGIS 10.3.1. Geometry storage is sde binary.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the RDBMS in use.  We'll also need to know the geometry storage of the geometry tables.  The most likely cause is using SDEBINARY or SDELOB storage, which are not Query Layer-ready (since they don't use native storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

Like @Vince said, SDEBinary is not query layer ready because it isn't a DBMS spatial type.  That integer is a a foreign key to the feature table (aka F table) which stores the geometry as a Blob.  Only geodatabase connections can read this type of feature class, query layers and connections from non-ESRI clients can not.

To make this layer usable with query layers, the easiest ways are to run the [Migrate Storage GP Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/migrate-storage.htm) or reload the table.  In either case you'll have to use a [dbtune keyword](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/configuration-keywords-for-enterprise-geodatabases.htm) that specifies the GEOMETRY_STORAGE as a native type ([GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY for SQLServer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/sqlserver-spatial-types-and-arcgis.htm)).

Comment: If i have ArcGIS Server services and wms services using these Feature Classes as a source, will I have to republish them? Are there any other considerations when migrating storag which will need to be considered?

Comment: I would republish the service.  You will definitely need to stop the service, I'm not sure what behaviour you will get once you restart it.  There is a help topic that outline SQL Server migration, it does a better job describing all the considerations than I could. (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/data-migration.htm).  Also, backups are your friend.